# How to ignore Cloudflare for my uploader?

Tags: cloudflare

On my site I upload media files. My uploader chunks these uploads into smaller sized files and once the upload is completed, the original will be created by merging the chunks.

The issue I run into is that when Cloudflare is enabled, the chunking request takes an awful long amount of time. An example is displayed here: http://testnow.ga

Every uploaded 5mb it chunks the file. This process saves the downloaded file on the server, then sends an AJAX request to the client and another 5mb upload request starts. The waiting (TTFB) in this particular case ranges anywhere from 2-10 seconds. Now, when the chunk size is 50mb for example, the waiting can be up to two minutes.

How can I speed up this process with Cloudflare? How can I ignore that specific /upload URL to not talk to Cloudflare?

Ps: the reason I'm not asking at Cloudflare is because I did a week ago and again a few days ago and haven't gotten a response yet. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use a subdomain to submit the data to. At cloudflare, greycloud that dns entry. Then data is sent directly to your server bypassing cloudflare.